# Russian transcript of English words in python

Tags: python

I am looking to create program which would generate Russian transcript of English words (this it not exactly translation). For example:

`watct` to `уотч`

`and` to `энд`

I came across the following tools:

[transliterate](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/transliterate)

[CyrTranslit](http://pythonhosted.org/cyrtranslit/)

But either there are bugs in them or they are not working.

So I will probably have to start from scratch. Creating simple look up dictionary probably will not work, so I am guessing I would neural network for it. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you should go for it. Try it for yourself, then if you get stuck, ask a specific question on what isn't working, and make sure to post an [MCVE]. Until then, this question is likely to attract opinions since it's just a "what do you think is best" kind of question.

Comment: I think, on the contrary, a lookup dictionary will work fine, although it's probably gonna be pretty big. A neural network will be an overkill, to my mind. You'd probably need an _RNN_ to do this, not a plain fully-connected one, which is, again, not worth the effort. Also, `transliterate` seems very easy to use and fits your need exactly.

Comment: @ForceBru, `transliterate` has some letters issues. `watch` produces `wатч`